# Keep the leading zeros of a string when exporting to CSV in Golang

Tags: csv, go, export-to-csv, go-gin

I have a Go application using Gin framework that exports a struct to CSV. One column `userCode` requires the exported field keeping all the leading zeros of the string.

For example, for string such as `000001`, `010101`, `000000`, the exported field in CSV should have the exact similar value. However, if I directly append the string to the row and write to the buffer, the exported field will emit all the leading zeros and the value becomes: `1`, `10101`,  , I did some digging and it seems this problem can be fixed by setting column type in Excel when reading the csv file, but I was wondering if this can be solved within Go program? Thanks!

My CSV export related function:

```golang
func (h *HandleManager) ExportUsers() gin.HandlerFunc {

        var buf bytes.Buffer
        writer := csv.NewWriter(&buf)
        var cols = []string{"User Name", ..., ....}
        writer.Write(cols)
        for _, e := range users {
            var row []string
            // ....
            row = append(row, e.userCode) // type: string
            if err := writer.Write(row); err != nil {
                log.Errorff(h.logCtx, "ExportUsers|WriteToCSV|err:%v", err)
                c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
        }
        writer.Flush()
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/csv")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+csvFileName+".csv")
        c.Writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
}
```

Comment: See [Formatting a comma-delimited CSV to force Excel to interpret value as a string](https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the proposal but I tried `row = append(row, "=\"\""+e.userCode+"\"\"")`, `row = append(row, "\t"+e.userCode)`, `row = append(row, "\"=\"\""+e.userCode+"\"\"\"")` and none of them worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tries I found the solution that worked in golang,thanks to the link @Steffen Ullrich posed. Similar to which worked in VB, instead of two quotation marks on both sides, one should be enough:

```golang
row = append(row, "=\""+e. userCode +"\"")
```

will contain all the leading zeros in the CSV file:

```
000001, 010101, 000000
```

Comment: Your answer has machine dependency. If we apply this we get following result in excel ="010101" on ubuntu 22.04 & older version of mac. Do have any idea about how to handle this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

1. I tested your code, and the result in excel would loss the zeros, but in txt reader would not;
2. code:

   func main() {
   type user struct {
   Name string
   Code string
   }

   ```
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        writer := csv.NewWriter(&buf)
        var cols = []string{"Name", "Code"}
        writer.Write(cols)
        users := []user{{Name: "Tome", Code: "001"}, {Name: "James", Code: "000"}}

        for _, e := range users {
            err := writer.Write([]string{e.Name, e.Code})
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
        }
        writer.Flush()
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/csv")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+"test.csv")

        w.Write(buf.Bytes())

    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
   ```

   }

result：
[image]

Comment: yes I'm aware however the project requirement restricts the csv reader to Excel. My answer above should produce the correct value in Excel.